# JPQL query - order by count

Tags: sql, jpa, hql, jpql

I need to implement a named query, that returns a list of events sorted by number of friends who go to the event.

For example, this query return a list of events sorted by number of all people who go to event:

```
    SELECT r.event
    FROM RSVP AS r 
    JOIN r.event.rsvpList rr 
    WHERE r.profile.user.uuid = :userUuid 
    AND r.rsvpStatus = RSVPStatus.ATTENDING 
    GROUP BY r.event 
    ORDER BY COUNT(rr) DESC
```

Or other example, list of friends events:

```
        SELECT r.event 
        FROM RSVP AS r 
        WHERE r.profile IN 
            (   SELECT f.profileTo 
                FROM Friend f 
                WHERE f.profileFrom.user.uuid = :userUuid
            )
        AND r.rsvpStatus = :rsvpStatus  
        GROUP BY r.event
```

I tried to do the following:

```
    SELECT r.event
    FROM RSVP AS r 
    JOIN r.event.rsvpList rr 
    WHERE r.profile.user.uuid = :userUuid 
    AND r.rsvpStatus = RSVPStatus.ATTENDING
    AND rr.profile IN
        (
            SELECT f.profileTo 
            FROM Friend f 
            WHERE f.profileFrom.user.uuid = :userUuid
        )       
    GROUP BY r.event 
    ORDER BY COUNT(rr) DESC
```

But this query returned the events that go on friends and skip other events.

This is a simplified diagram of my DB:
[image: Scheme]

Comment: @Aquillo, sorry, posted a question ahead of time.

Comment: is the problem the order by, or the results in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your entities so i could not try, but i think this should work:

```
SELECT r.event, (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM RSVP rr
    WHERE rr.event = r.event
        AND rr.profile IN
        (
            SELECT f.profileTo 
            FROM Friend f 
            WHERE f.profileFrom.user.uuid = :userUuid
        )
    ) count
FROM RSVP AS r 
WHERE r.profile.user.uuid = :userUuid 
    AND r.rsvpStatus = RSVPStatus.ATTENDING      
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

The thing here is HQL does not support subqueries in the `ORDER BY` clause, so you have to select one more column just for ordering.

Comment: Thank you! As a result, I used this query.